# disable reset password page in liferay 6.2 ga2

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

In liferay 6.2 to  Disable Reset New password page from user Login the
following properties were added in portal-ext.properties file.

## To turn off password reset page

passwords.default.policy.change.required=false

but still the new user when he logs in for the first time in liferay can view reset password page  and user can reset his password.

if anyone knows the solution how to disable password reset page in liferay 6.2 please share the solution. it would be great help.

thanks in advance

Comment: This property should do the job,Can you try altering some other property just to check if the properties are being retrieved from the correct file.

Answer (score 0):

Some properties can be changed in portal-ext.properties after first installation, but some of them can't. 
Furthermore, if you change some property at the control panel, you won't be able to manage it from properties file anymore, as it goes to the database.

When a property change has no effect, the first thing to look at is who manages it (file or database). You can see it in your control panel:
http://localhost:8080/group/control_panel/manage/-/server/properties/portal-properties
Search for your property and look at the origin icon. It can be a file or a database. If it's a database, you must go to the passwords policy administration to manage it.

Answer (score -2):

You can set properties in portal-ext like `users.form.update.main=details,organizations,sites,roles`
Restart the server and the problem is solved.